# Ext-gwt (gxt) TextField getFieldValue() problem

Tags: gwt, textfield, gxt

I have an TextField with datatype Integer, so I am trying to getFieldValue() and write it to Integer field. So in runtime I have an error here:

```
TextField<Integer> priceField = new  TextField<Integer>();
Integer newPriceFieldValue = priceField.getValue(); //here is an error in runtime
```

So I cant understand whats the problem - proceField.getValue() should be Integer, why string? Maybe I should another type of Field?

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Integer
>       at
>   ru.braginini.client.ProductForm$2.componentSelected(ProductForm.java:64)
>       at
>   ru.braginini.client.ProductForm$2.componentSelected(ProductForm.java:1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are expecting only numbers to be used in this field [NumberField](http://www.sencha.com/gxtdocs/#com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.NumberField) may be the better choice.

```
    NumberField field = new NumberField();
    field.setPropertyEditorType(Integer.class);
```

It will ensure only numbers are entered, and save you some casting & error handling on the getValue() call.

Answer (score 0):

getValue returns a String!
You want to assign this String to an Integer which causes an CastException (like it would in any Type oriented Programming language.

Try

```
Integer newPriceFieldValue = Integer.parseInt(priceField.getValue());
```

Regards,
Stefan

Comment: Stefan, I tried, but didnt'wok cause the IDE said that priceField.getValue() integer

Comment: Integer newIdFieldValue = (Integer) idField.getValue(); - that rocks, thx :)